# Bootstrap DatePicker, how to set the start date for to 15 mins. in the future?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Is there any way to have the startDate be 15 minutes from current time, something like this:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var fifteenminslater - new Date(currentDate.getTime() + (20*60*1000));

     $( ".datepicker" ).datetimepicker({
         pickTime: true,
         pick12HourFormat: true,
         startDate: fifteenminslater  });
```

I think startDate only knows date, and not time. Is there something similar to startDate that will allow me to mess with the time?

Comment: Can you specify which library (and which version of it) you're using?  Bootstrap out of the box does not appear to have any plugins do do with datepickers (or datetimepickers).

Comment: Which datetimepicker are you using? The eonasdan one uses `defaultDate` not `startDate`.